# Allocating heap memory to return to a calling function

Tags: c, string, malloc

How do I correctly allocate heap memory in a function so its caller can use the pointer passed in?
For example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void test(char *arg) {
    arg = malloc(3);
    strcpy(arg,"hi");
}

int main() {
    char *x = NULL;
    test(x);
    printf("%s\n",x); //should print "hi", instead does nothing
    return 0;
}
```

I have also tried to use `strdup` but cannot get main to correctly print the string I assign the pointer to in the test function, but I always get garbage data or a segfault.

To be clear, I cannot modify the signature of `test` in any way, so double pointers or returning a pointer are not valid solutions. It is possible to return a different string using a `char*` argument?)

Comment: I cannot use the solutions marked as duplicates because they require changing the function signature to pass a string using **char or by returning a char pointer.

Comment: It’s impossible. You have no way of communicating the new memory address back to the caller short of using global state.

Comment: Don't pass ```NULL```. allocate at main(), and pass it, don't allocate in test(),  copy string.. Simple, Hah ??!!

Comment: if you can't change the signature of `test`, then it's a useless function. Everything in C is pass by value, so the only way to modify an argument _and_ have that modification persist outside the scope of the function is by returning it, or passing in the address and dereferencing it in the function to modify it. `x` and `arg` are 2 different variables with 2 different addresses. Modifying `arg` in `test` has no bearing on `x` any more than if their types were `int`. All `test` does here is create a memory leak.